# Move a device mapper table from INACTIVE to LIVE without unsuspending

Tags: linux, device-mapper

When a device mapper target is suspended, the table can be changed, causing the new table to move into the INACTIVE state. The INACTIVE table is changed to LIVE when the target resumes:

```
# dmsetup info test | grep -E '^(State|Tables present): '
State:             ACTIVE
Tables present:    LIVE
# dmsetup suspend test
# dmsetup info test | grep -E '^(State|Tables present): '
State:             SUSPENDED
Tables present:    LIVE
# dmsetup reload --table "$newtable" test
# dmsetup info test | grep -E '^(State|Tables present): '
State:             SUSPENDED
Tables present:    LIVE & INACTIVE
# dmsetup resume test
# dmsetup info test | grep -E '^(State|Tables present): '
State:             ACTIVE
Tables present:    LIVE
```

Is there any way to switch the INACTIVE table to LIVE **without** unsuspending the target?